# Как использовать form action="" если сервлет примаплен к корню?

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Есть сервлет который отвечает на запросы к корню:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SignInServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ru.pravvich.servlets.SignInServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SignInServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

И есть форма которая через doPost на него ссылается:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Меню">
</form>
```

Но когда происходит переход на страницу URL в адресной строке не меняется.

Он как был `http://localhost:8080/items/answer` так после перехода и остается, а мне надо чтобы путь обрезался до `http://localhost:8080/items/`. Подскажите как мне решить эту проблему?

Comment: action="#{request.contextPath}/" или action="#{pageContext.request.contextPath}/"

Comment: `<form action=".." method="post">`?

Comment: если подключен `jstl` указывать: `action="<c:url value="/" />"`